How to label each function graph as originating from a Taylor expansion or a Padé approximation?
My question is:
For any given function ( f(x) ), I want to automatically calculate its Padé approximant and Taylor expansion using code, and plot them on the same Cartesian coordinate system. I would like to label the corresponding Padé approximant and Taylor expansion of the function ( f(x) ) in the graph to indicate whether it is a Taylor expansion or a Padé approximation, and to display the corresponding function expressions. The specific desired effect is shown in the following figure:
f[x_] := Cos[x]
Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], 
   Table[Normal@Series[f[x], {x, 0, 2 n + 1}], {n, 2}], 
   Table[PadeApproximant[f[x], {x, 0, n}], {n, 2}]}], {x, -2 \[Pi], 
  2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotLabels -> "Expressions",
  ImageSize -> Large]

The desired effect is something like this:

It means marking something like "Taylor, order 1: 1 - x^2/2" on the extension line behind each function curve.The identification can be adaptively added through code, as the function curve will automatically expand or contract with changes in parameters.

Just specify the label explicitly.
f[x_] := Cos[x]
Plot[Evaluate[
  Flatten@{Callout[f[x], "" Rasterize[f[x]]], 
    Table[Callout[Normal[Series[f[x], {x, 0, 2  n + 1}]], 
      "Taylor, order " <> ToString[n] <> ": "  Rasterize[
        Normal[Series[f[x], {x, 0, 2  n + 1}]]]], {n, 2}], 
    Table[Callout[PadeApproximant[f[x], {x, 0, n}], 
      "Pade, order " <> ToString[n] <> ": "  Rasterize[
        Normal[PadeApproximant[f[x], {x, 0, n}]]]], {n, 
      2}]}], {x, -2   \[Pi], 2   \[Pi]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 ImagePadding -> {{20, 180}, {20, 5}}]



This identification can be automatically added through code, as the function curve will automatically increase or decrease with parameter changes.

@csn899 As you wish.
